# How to redirect user to settings menu of telegram where they can enter username

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Can we open telegram's setting menu with any code or redirecting?
I made a bot on telegram which needs username for a specific actions. If a user don't have any username then the bot replies something like 'Username not found please go to settings and set a username to continue'. Instead of this I want to redirect the user to settings menu where username can be added. Any suggestions how I can do that? Like I have seen many bots who redirect users to groups list so that they can add them to any group. Can we do same for settings menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, Telegram does not allow users to open the profile settings with an url, but you can click on this url on a Telegran app to open the settings menu: tg://settings (does not seems to work on my Android with Telegram Beta but on TGDesktop it works just fine). The "open groups list" is a deep linking url: https://t.me/usernameBot?startgroup=test. If specified, the `startgroup` parameter asks the user to select a group from the list.

---

For more info:

[Deep Linking](https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking)

[Deep Link Channel](https://t.me/DeepLink)

Answer (score 0):

To open profile settings with bot, you need to redirect users to the "tg://settings".